# Python 3.6 - Cannot get current stock prices from quandl, pandas and datetime

Tags: python, datetime, stock, quandl, pandas-datareader

I try to write a small "program" that gets the stock prices from Quandl.
The user should be able to enter a startring date (yyyymmdd) and the the program should then get the data from that date and forward to current date.

```
import datetime as dt                
import pandas_datareader as web  

ticker = 'TSLA'

# Time variables for current and starting date as integers
current_year = int(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y"))
current_month = int(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%m"))
current_day = int(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%d"))

start_date = str(input("Starting date (yyyymmdd): "))
start_year = int(start_date[:4])
start_month = int(start_date[5:6])
start_day = int(start_date[7:8])


# Defines the total period
start = dt.datetime(start_year, start_month, start_day)           # Starting date, yyyy mm dd
end = dt.datetime(current_year, current_month, current_day)       # End date, yyyy mm dd


# Gets the data from start to end date for the stock definded as 'Ticker'
df = web.get_data_quandl(ticker, start, end)

print(start)
print(end)

print(df)
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to get any data newer than 2018-03-27.

Answer (score 1):

The WIKI database is indeed no longer updated or supported starting from March 27, 2018. The closest alternative on Quandl is EOD, which is a value-priced end-of-day US stock price data feed.